# How to write a function expression formally/correct?

Tags: functions

Lets us take an example: the funktion $f(x)=x^2$. I how realised that this notation does not make much sense. But how would one write it then?

How about the following:

$$f:x\mapsto x^2$$

I'm worried that it will be confused with $f:A \longrightarrow B$, where $A$ is the domain and $B$ is the codomain.

Can you guys suggest a "better" notation?

Comment: If you're going for precision, then you don't have to care if someone confuses $\mapsto$ and $\to$ as long as you're technically right...but what is the problem with the first? I have not seen anyone object to $f(x) = x^2$. Some people object to calling $x^2$ a function. This at least I can understand but disagree with.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2$ mixes the value of a function at the point $x$ with the function expression itself.

Comment: Oh, so are you're objecting to the fact that we did  not define $f$ (at least not directly), but only the action of $f$ on each point?

Comment: A function is a subset of the cartesian product $A\times B$, with the properties that for every $a\in A$ there is exactly one element $(a,b)$ in the Cartesian product. So formally, you can write a function $f$ by describing this subset. However, I also do not really see what is wrong with both notations you gave.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Exactly.

Comment: Do you have any problem with defining a sequence like $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2$, and in general $a_n = 2^{n-1}$?

Comment: Functions are defined by their actions

Answer (score 0):

When you write $f(x) = x^{2}$, you are saying that the application of $f$ at an element $x$ is given by $x^{2}$; in other words, you are evaluating $f$ at some $x$. When the function depends on one variable only, we usually use this as a representation of the map which is defined by $f$ because $x$ is assumed to be arbitrary and $x$ is a dumb variable. When we consider functions of two variables, for instance, this representation sometimes has to be enhanced when one wants to make explicit the difference of an application of $f$ at an arbitrary point and $f$ as a function which depends on some variable. This is why, sometimes, we write $f(x,y)$ as $f(\cdot, y)$; this means that $f$ is fixed at some arbitrary value of $y$ and is a function of $x$ only. The notation $x \mapsto x^{2}$ is a more direct one, and it captures the essence of the map but it does not make the domain or range explicit, so this is more like a quick notation. To me, the more complete representation of a function whose domain is $A$ and the range is $B$ is written as $$\begin{align} f: A &\to B \\ x &\to f(x) = x^{2}\end{align}$$